# "Правильное" создание объекта на php?

Tags: php, ооп

У меня несколько вопросов по объектам. В пхп при создании объект уже имеет значение не null. Поэтому, собственно, первый вопрос - как правильно (по хорошему тону) просигнализировать что при создании объекта произошли ошибка: бросить исключение с именем ошибки? Получается что любое неудачное действие метода должно сопровождаться брошенным исключением чтобы было ясно, что что-то пошло не так? И еще, перед выполнением какого-то метод объекта можно ли перед каждым эти методом с помощью средств самого пхп вызывать повторяющийся код (например создание соединения с бд, очистка содержимого свойств с именем и кодом ошибки) или для этого нужно просто создать свой внутренний метод и вызывать его по мере необходимости (опять, же, если следовать хорошему тону). Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибок при создании объекта, можно избежать, явно указывая тип входных параметров в конструкторе. По хорошему, результат создания экземпляра класса не должен зависеть ни от каких других факторов кроме переданных в конструктор аргументов. Если же на вход приходит, к примеру, объект верного типа, но не верно сконфигурированный, правильно будет выбросить исключение, и оборачивать код создания объекта в блоки try-catch. Второй вариант, возложить ответственность за создание таких объектов на некий третий объект "фабрику", который будет проверять конфигурацию входных параметров, и, в случае не удовлетворения условиям, выбрасывать исключение, а в случае, если все условия соблюденны, создавать экземпляр искомого класса.
По поводу второй части вопроса, есть такие варианты:

1. вызывать внутренние методы по мере необходимости, их так же можно вынести в "супер-тип слоя" - базовый абстрактный класс иерархии, если эти методы общие для всех классов в иерархии.
2. Заморочиться с магическими методами (`__call`, `__callStatic`) - http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php .
3. Вас может заинтересовать аспектно-ориентированный подход - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5. Вот фреймворк, который достойно реализует это на PHP - https://github.com/goaop/framework, советую ознакомиться.

Comment: Спасибо за линки, посмотрю. По поводу первого вопроса - у меня проблемный вопрос не правильность параметров, а результат работы функций подключения к БД, фтп и другим сервисам. То есть пользователь передает объекту хост и данные для входа на нужный сервис, и в зависимости от того удачное ли подключение или нет - создается объект, который с этим сервисом работает. Я так понял, что, наверное, исключения таки будет правильнее всего использовать.

Comment: такие блоки в любом случае должны использовать исключения (либо каким то другим образом обрабатывать исключительные ситуации, во времена PHP4 перебивались объектами `PEAR_ERROR`, имея на данный момент реализованный механизм исключений в самом языке, не вижу смысла, придумывать что-то другое).

Comment: Я понял, спасибо.

Comment: *и оборачивать код создания объекта в блоки try-catch* - нет, подобные случаи являются ошибкой программиста и не должны отлавливаться. Если код неправильно используется, проще сразу прекратить его работу, нежели пытаться продолжить.

Comment: В целом соглашусь, спасибо за замечание. По хорошему вообще не давать возможность создать не верно сконфигурированный объект, или, что даже более частый случай, не давать создать не полностью сконфигурированный объект, избегать т.н. temporal coupling. Т.е., если для корректной работы метода someMethod экземпляра класса aClass необходимым условием является проинициализированное поле aClass::strategy объектом aStrategy, то класс aClass должен ожидать объект типа aStrategy в конструкторе.

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно заюзать: 
   [Исключения](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php)
   И сделать обработку исключений.
   С помощью наследования, можно создать свои обработчики.
2. Вызывать метод когда нужно, в котором уже ранее описаны действия для выполнения, чтобы избежать повторов в теле метода, есть замечательный модификатор static который может сохранить нужные нам данные после первой инициализации метода.

   function name($str) {
       static $name = null;
       if(!$name) {
           $name = $str;
       }
       return $name;
   }
   echo name(1); // 1
   echo name(2); // 1

Comment: По поводу второго пункта спасибо, хороший совет со статической переменной. А по поводу первого: то есть каждый раз, когда что-то не так выбрасывать исключение? Или в самом объекте устанавливать/менять какие-то свойства, чтобы было ясно что произошла ошибка?

Comment: Отвратительный модификатор static. Теперь с чем бы вы ни вызвали тот метод, возвращать он все равно будет одно и то же даже с другими экземплярами класса.

Answer (score 0):

Немного дополню отмеченный правильным ответ.

1.Создавать объекты, как было сказано выше, можно по-разному, но, вообще, желательно всё оборачивать в блоки `try-catch` и на разных уровнях либо обрабатывать исключение, либо "проталкивать" выше. Пример:

```
<?php

class MyClass {

    /**
     * Обработка исключения внутри метода
     */
    public function some_public_method() {
        try {
            $this->some_private_method();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Обработаем исключение в методе ({$e->getMessage()})";
        }
    }

    /**
     * "Проталкивание" исключения выше
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function some_public_method2() {
        try {
            $this->some_private_method();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    private function some_private_method() {
        throw new Exception("Произошла ужасная ошибка");
    }

}

try {
    $obj = new MyClass();
    $obj->some_public_method();
    echo "\n";
    $obj->some_public_method2();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Обработаем исключение снаружи ({$e->getMessage()})";
}
?>
```

2.*"а можно ли перед каждым эти методом с помощью средств самого пхп вызывать повторяющийся код"*. Да, можно! Есть множество вариантов, например:

Вариант 1 (вызывать нужный код в начале исполняемого метода):

```
<?php

class MyClass {

    public function some_public_method() {
        //Либо $this->какой_нибудь_метод_этого_класса
        //Либо просто какой-нибудь php-код
        //Возможно создание объекта другого класса и работа с ним
        //и что угодно

        echo "Что-то дальше делаем";
    }

}
?>
```

Но, на мой взгляд, это практически всегда плохое решение, т.к. объект не должен знать "cлишком много". Почитайте про [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Так что для решения этой задачи можно (и нужно) ипользовать какой-нибудь другой класс.

Вариант 2 ("Оборачиваем" объект в другой объект):

```
<?php

class MyClass {

    public function some_public_method() {
        echo "Что-то делаем";
    }

}

class MyClassWrapper {

    public function get_my_class_some_method_with_additional_code() {
        /**
         * Какой угодно код
         */
        $obj = new MyClass();
        $obj->some_public_method();
    }

}
?>
```

Вариант 3: Есть такой паттерн "Внедрение зависимостей (Dependency Injection)". Почитайте о нем, в интернет полно информации на русском языке, поэтому даже не знаю какую ссылку Вам привести.

Comment: Спасибо за инфу, буду разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

> Поэтому, собственно, первый вопрос - как правильно (по хорошему тону) просигнализировать что при создании объекта произошли ошибка: бросить исключение с именем ошибки?

Верным ответом здесь будет "конструктор не должен быть построен таким образом, что в нем может возникнуть ошибка". В конструкторе не должно быть никакой логики, создание объекта само по себе должно быть бесплатным, а все тяжелые инициализационные процессы должны вызываться отдельными методами; зона ответственности конструктора - присвоение аргументов свойствам объекта. Если вы прячете что-то в конструктор, это а) обязательно выполнится и б) будет скрыто для модификации, поэтому если у вас внутри есть ошибка в логике, исправить ее будет невозможно.

http://www.daedtech.com/beware-the-bloated-constructor/

В случае, если у вас не ошибка как таковая, а ошибка валидации, то следует бросать InvalidArgumentException, которые де-факто является флагом программисту о том, что он использует предоставленный ему код неправильно, передавая неверные значения.

> Получается что любое неудачное действие метода должно сопровождаться брошенным исключением чтобы было ясно, что что-то пошло не так?

Это зависит от степени ответственности кода и непосредственно его предназначения. У кода либо есть ответственность за обработку некоторых исключений (e.g. менеджер подключений БД имеет право записать в соседнюю БД, если основная вдруг упала, и таким образом обработать исключение) или нет (класс подключения БД не имеет права скрыть информацию о том, что запись не прошла, однако имеет право словить ошибку/исключение и обернуть в исключение своего типа). В то же время ошибка может быть ожидаемой (e.g. выполнение запроса `SELECT 1` для проверки подключения к базе в виде метода `isAlive()`), в этом случае нужно вернуть соответствующее значение (false) вместо выброса исключения.

В любом случае при написании метода вам нужно спрашивать самого себя: *Должен ли этот участок кода выбрасывать исключение? Должен ли он передавать информацию об ошибке выше?*. Несмотря на то, что я возвращаю вам ваш же вопрос, иначе определить необходимость выброса исключения просто невозможно.

> И еще, перед выполнением какого-то метод объекта можно ли перед каждым эти методом с помощью средств самого пхп вызывать повторяющийся код (например создание соединения с бд, очистка содержимого свойств с именем и кодом ошибки) или для этого нужно просто создать свой внутренний метод и вызывать его по мере необходимости

Про AOP уже ответили; я же просто дополню, что AOP хорош для задач своей специфики (e.g. профилирование методов), а в большинстве случаев стоит просто объявить метод `ensureConnected()` или аналог и вызывать его. Еще не могу не отметить, что эти примеры

> например создание соединения с бд, очистка содержимого свойств с именем и кодом ошибки

являются дикими антипаттернами. Соединение с БД должно создаваться один раз, управление ошибками должно быть только через исключения.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения, учту. Просто опыта ооп на практике никакого не было, поэтому и появляются такие вопросы.